# Pass a hash object from a perl script to through bsub (LSF)

Tags: perl, system, lsf

This is an extension to my older question: [Pass a hash object from one perl script to another using system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086047/pass-a-hash-object-from-one-perl-script-to-another-using-system). @Sobrique answered my question there.

Now, I want to know if I can pass an hash object to another perl script in the same way as my question above but using `bsub`.

wrapper script: script1.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable qw ( freeze  );
use MIME::Base64;

my %test_hash = (
    "fish"   => "paste",
    "apples" => "pears"
);

my $frozen = encode_base64 freeze( \%test_hash );
my ${string} = 'sample1';

# instead of just using system like this
# system("perl", "some_other_script.pl", $frozen);
# I want to use something like this:
system('bsub','-J',${string},'-o','${string}.out','-e','${string}.err','perl','some_other_script.pl',$frozen);
```

some_other_script.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable qw ( thaw );
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64;

# should read the imported hash correctly and print it out
my ($imported_scalar) = @ARGV; 
print $imported_scalar;
my %param =  %{ thaw (decode_base64 $imported_scalar ) };
print $param{'fish'};
print "\n";
```

How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did this work when you tried it? What error did you get?

Comment: the hash is not getting returned, only a reference to the hash.

Comment: I looked at the .out file and it says: `# LSBATCH: User input
perl some_other_script.pl BAcIMTIzNDU2NzgECAgIAwIAAAAKBXBlYXJzBgAAAGFwcGxlcwoFcGFzdGUEAAAAZmlzaA==`

Answer (score 0):

This is really more a question about [`bsub`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.2/lsf_command_ref/bsub.1.html) than `perl`. Passing arguments via Base64 encoded parameters might do the trick, but actually if your purpose is passing data into the batch processing system, it might be worth using an input file:

If you have a look through the `bsub` manpage, you'll see:

> -i input_file | -is input_file

That's probably a better way of handing 'input' to your batch job.